# Setting color of ul tag in HTML.

Tags: html, css

In the below code I want to set the color of @HTML.Authorized to red.  When I did `<ul style="color: red;">` it is not working for me.

```
<li><a><i class="glyph-icon icon-folder-open-alt" style="color: #009900;"></i><span><b><font color="#111111">@Resources.LanguageStrings.WorkOrders</font></b></span></a>
        <ul>
            @Html.AuthorizedLink(Url.Action("IndexSite", "WorkOrder"), "Company Work Orders", user.IsInRole(SystemRoles.SystemAdmin | SystemRoles.CompanyAdmin | SystemRoles.CompanyEditor | SystemRoles.SupervisorUnlimited | SystemRoles.SupervisorLimited | SystemRoles.DemoAdmin))          
        </ul>
        </li>
```

Could you please suggest what should be the correct way to doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup looks a bit malformed.  It should be the following.

```
<ul>
   <li>Authorised</li>
</ul>
```

The reason why you do not see the red text is that you are styling the unordered list, rather than the list item.

```
ul li {
   color: red;
}
```

You may also want to select the first child or give the `li` item a class so it does not affect other list items if you decide to add more, you can achieve this by using the `first-child` selector.

```css
ul li:first-child {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Authorised</li>
   <li>Darren Test</li>
   <li>Darren Test 2</li>
</ul>
```

As an additional note, try not to use inline styling, separate it out into a CSS StyleSheet which will help maintain your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure from your code, is this what you're trying to do?

```
    <li><a><i class="glyph-icon icon-folder-open-alt" style="color: #009900;"></i><span><b><font color="#111111">@Resources.LanguageStrings.WorkOrders</font></b></span></a>
        <ul>
            <li style="color: red;">
            @Html.AuthorizedLink(Url.Action("IndexSite", "WorkOrder"), "Company Work Orders", user.IsInRole(SystemRoles.SystemAdmin | SystemRoles.CompanyAdmin | SystemRoles.CompanyEditor | SystemRoles.SupervisorUnlimited | SystemRoles.SupervisorLimited | SystemRoles.DemoAdmin))          
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a><i class="glyph-icon icon-folder-open-alt" style="color: #009900;"></i><span><b><font color="#111111">@Resources.LanguageStrings.WorkOrders</font></b></span></a>
        <ul>
            @Html.AuthorizedLink(Url.Action("IndexSite", "WorkOrder"), "Company Work Orders", user.IsInRole(SystemRoles.SystemAdmin | SystemRoles.CompanyAdmin | SystemRoles.CompanyEditor | SystemRoles.SupervisorUnlimited | SystemRoles.SupervisorLimited | SystemRoles.DemoAdmin), new { Style="color:red" })          
        </ul>
        </li>
```